# How to paste data from previous activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I'm trying here to make a project, that can scan a barcode (that is done), and after that it's supposed to show some values from a database based on that barcode (product name, address).

I manage to copy the value from the barcode to the clipboard, but then I cannot manage to copy it to the `activity_second.xml`'s EditText.

[image]

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
         <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             package="br.exemplozxingintegration"
             android:versionCode="1"
             android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="ScannerBucatarie"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="ScannerBucatarie"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="ZXing ScanBar"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_second"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Config.java**

```
package br.exemplozxingintegration;

/**
 * Created by Boghy on 09.02.2016.
 */
public class Config {
    public static final String DATA_URL = "http://192.168.94.1/test/getData.php?id=";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String KEY_VC = "vc";
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
}
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
package br.exemplozxingintegration;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText editTextId;
    private Button buttonGet;
    private TextView textViewResult;

    private ProgressDialog loading;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
        buttonGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGet);
        textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);

        buttonGet.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void getData() {
        String id = editTextId.getText().toString().trim();
        if (id.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter an id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

        String url = Config.DATA_URL+editTextId.getText().toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                loading.dismiss();
                showJSON(response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void showJSON(String response){
        String name="";
        String address="";
        String vc = "";
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
            name = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
            address = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_ADDRESS);
            vc = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_VC);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        textViewResult.setText("Name:\t"+name+"\nAddress:\t" +address+ "\nVice Chancellor:\t"+ vc);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getData();
    }
}`    AndroidManifet.xml 
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="br.exemplozxingintegration"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0">

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />     
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


Config.java

    package br.exemplozxingintegration;

    /**
     * Created by Boghy on 09.02.2016.
     */
    public class Config {
        public static final String DATA_URL = "http://192.168.94.1/test/getData.php?id=";
        public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
        public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
        public static final String KEY_VC = "vc";
        public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
    }
```

**activity_second.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".SecondActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txResult"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonGet"
            android:text="Get"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewResult"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#ddd" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Scan"
        android:onClick="callZXing"
        android:id="@+id/Button" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#ddd" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txResult"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rezultat:"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Is this the correct code?"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        style="@style/CaptureTheme"
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="sendSecond" />

    <Button
        style="@style/CaptureTheme"
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:text="No"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_weight="0.10"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="callZXing" />

</LinearLayout>
 SecondActivity.java

package br.exemplozxingintegration;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText editTextId;
    private Button buttonGet;
    private TextView textViewResult;

    private ProgressDialog loading;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
        buttonGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGet);
        textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);

        buttonGet.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void getData() {
        String id = editTextId.getText().toString().trim();
        if (id.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter an id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

        String url = Config.DATA_URL+editTextId.getText().toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                loading.dismiss();
                showJSON(response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void showJSON(String response){
        String name="";
        String address="";
        String vc = "";
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
            name = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
            address = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_ADDRESS);
            vc = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_VC);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        textViewResult.setText("Name:\t"+name+"\nAddress:\t" +address+ "\nVice Chancellor:\t"+ vc);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you pass it as an intent parameter?

Comment: How can I do that? @Natan

Comment: Have you tried googling it? https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=android+activity+intent+parameter&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: What do I need to modify to be able to pass it as an intent? @Natan

Answer (score 0):

In your main activity, set your data into Intent as below:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("Param_name", txtNumOfCards.getText().toString());

intent.setClass(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the second activity, you can retrieve it as below:

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getStringExtra("Param_name");
```

Checkout the following exmaple:

http://www.startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/241-lesson-28-extras-passing-data-using-intent.html

Comment: Doesn't work, it gives the same errors as before.Thanks a lot man ;)

Comment: What is the error, and please post the updated code.

Comment: I don't think I understand exactly, where and how I have to insert the code. And I am not sure, if Intent is able to copy the code from the clipboard straight to the activity_second.xml EditText. Sorry for not knowing how to Java.

Comment: In MainActivity, use the following code to set the parameter value and call the second activity:

Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.putExtra("Param_name", "Some text");

intent.setClass(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

In order to read the passed value from the first activity, in onCreate method in SecondActivity put the following code:
 Intent intent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getStringExtra("Param_name");

And forget about clipboard as its not needed.
Hope you find this solution helpful for you,

Comment: You can accept the answer if you found it helpful for you!

Answer (score 0):

As @Mohammed Kharma explained, you must send the id as an Intent extra (no need to copy it to the clipboard). I believe you already created this Intent, but I'm recreating it. Have in mind that I don't know the name you chose for your intent, so I'll just call it 'i'.

On your MainActivity.java:

```
Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.class,SecondActivity.java);
i.putExtra("barcode",txtResult.getText().toString());
startActivity(i);
```

On your SecondActivity.java:

```
    textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
    String barcode=getIntent().getStringExtra("barcode");
    textViewResult.setText(barcode);
```