# Adding MySQL to my Java Program

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-layout, android-intent

My program is a barcode scanner that takes a value(string) and searches the database for the description of the project.

I cannot connect to the database,    I am unable to copy the value that I get in activity_main.xml in the text field in activity_second.xml(where the database search should happen).

Activity_main.xml

> ```
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:weightSum="1">
>
>     <View
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="1dp"
>         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
>         android:background="#ddd" />
>
>     <Button
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Scan"
>         android:onClick="callZXing"
>         android:id="@+id/Button" />
>
>     <View
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="1dp"
>         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
>         android:background="#ddd" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/txResult"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Rezultat:"
>         android:textSize="20sp" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
>         android:text="Is this the correct code?"
>         android:id="@+id/textView"
>         android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
>         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
>
>     <Button
>         style="@style/CaptureTheme"
>         android:layout_width="112dp"
>         android:layout_height="68dp"
>         android:text="Yes"
>         android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
>         android:id="@+id/button2"
>         android:layout_weight="0.10"
>         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>         android:onClick="sendSecond" />
>
>     <Button
>         style="@style/CaptureTheme"
>         android:layout_width="112dp"
>         android:layout_height="68dp"
>         android:text="No"
>         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
>         android:id="@+id/button1"
>         android:layout_weight="0.10"
>         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>         android:onClick="callZXing" />
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

activity_second.xml

> ```
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
>     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
>     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:orientation="horizontal"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>
>         <EditText
>             android:id="@+id/editTextId"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="1"/>
>         <Button
>             android:id="@+id/buttonGet"
>             android:text="Get"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
>
>     </LinearLayout>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textViewResult"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

SecondActivity.java

> ```
> package br.exemplozxingintegration;
>
> import android.app.ProgressDialog;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.widget.Button;
> import android.widget.EditText;
> import android.widget.TextView;
> import android.widget.Toast;
> import android.app.Activity;
>
> import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
> import com.android.volley.Response;
> import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
> import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
> import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
>
> import org.json.JSONArray;
> import org.json.JSONException;
> import org.json.JSONObject;
>
>     public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
>
>         private EditText editTextId;
>         private Button buttonGet;
>         private TextView textViewResult;
>
>         private ProgressDialog loading;
>
>         @Override
>         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>             setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
>
>             editTextId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
>             buttonGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGet);
>             textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
>
>             buttonGet.setOnClickListener(this);
>         }
>
>         private void getData() {
>             String id = editTextId.getText().toString().trim();
>             if (id.equals("")) {
>                 Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter an id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>                 return;
>             }
>             loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);
>
>             String url = Config.DATA_URL+editTextId.getText().toString().trim();
>
>             StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onResponse(String response) {
>                     loading.dismiss();
>                     showJSON(response);
>                 }
>             },
>                     new Response.ErrorListener() {
>                         @Override
>                         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
>                             Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>                         }
>                     });
>
>             RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
>             requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
>         }
>
>         private void showJSON(String response){
>             String name="";
>             String address="";
>             String vc = "";
>             try {
>                 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
>                 JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
>                 JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
>                 name = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
>                 address = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_ADDRESS);
>                 vc = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_VC);
>             } catch (JSONException e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             }
>             textViewResult.setText("Name:\t"+name+"\nDescriere:\t" +address+ "\nImagine:\t"+ vc);
>         }
>
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             getData();
>         }
>     }
>
>
>
>   //  @Override
>
>     //protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>        // super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>       //  setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
>   //  }
>
> //}
> ```

MainActivity.java

> ```
> package br.exemplozxingintegration;
>
>
> import android.app.Activity;
> import android.content.Intent;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.widget.TextView;
>
> public class MainActivity extends Activity {
>   public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0;
>   private TextView txResult;
>
>
>
>   @Override
>   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>       txResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txResult);
>   }
>
>   public void sendSecond(View view) {
>       Intent StartNewActivity  =  new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
>       startActivity(StartNewActivity);
>   }
>
>
>   public void callZXing(View view){
>       Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.class);
>       startActivityForResult(it, REQUEST_CODE);
>   }
>
>
>   @Override
>   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
>       if(REQUEST_CODE == requestCode && RESULT_OK == resultCode){
>           txResult.setText("REZULTAT: "+data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT")+" ");
>       }
>   }
>   public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
>
>       @Override
>       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>           findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>               @Override
>               public void onClick(View v) {
>                   TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txResult);
>                   Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
>                   intent.putExtra("textViewText", textView.getText().toString());
>                   startActivity(intent);
>               }
>           });
>       }}
> }
> ```

Config.java

> ```
> package br.exemplozxingintegration;
>
> /**
>  * Created by Boghy on 10.02.2016.
>  */
> public class Config {
>     public static final String DATA_URL = "http://192.168.94.1/Android/College/getData.php?id=";
>     public static final String KEY_NAME = "title";
>     public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "desc";
>     public static final String KEY_VC = "image";
>     public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
> }
> ```

Comment: My advice is to decompose this problem into smaller pieces that can be tested separately.  You don't need a UI to connect to a database and do a query with a WHERE class that uses your search string.  Get that working, test it, and let other objects use it.

Comment: Isn't that really similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300642/how-to-paste-data-from-previous-activity)?? if not a duplicate for that matter?